# Send email to account email address

Tags: email

I have an email address on the account object. Is it possible to send an email to that address using one of the salesforce email templates I created?
Tia

Update:

I created an email field on Account: "Account_Email__c"

I want to be able to use this email address when I send out an email from within Salesforce. Basically when I am in the Account and I click on "Send Email" in my Activities related list, then I want to be able to send it to the email address that I specified on the account.

Comment: Yes, you can use workflows and email alerts to do so as long as the field is of an email type

Comment: Hi Lily, could you elaborate more? Do you want to send one-time email, or send email on a scheduled basis, or when certain criteria are met?

Comment: @BrianMansfield - I have added more detail

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom button "Send Email To Account Email" and use a link such as: /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&p24={!Account.Account_Email__c}

Where p24 = Additional To box of the Send Email Form.